# Error: Producing duplicates C#

Tags: c#

So I want to randomly generate unique values into my `listbox`, however I find that when `\t` is added it produces duplicates. How can I add a tab without generating duplicates in my `listbox`:

```
while (lstNumberList.Items.Count < MAX_ITEMS)
{
    int value = rnd.Next(101);
    if (!lstNumberList.Items.Contains(value))
       lstNumberList.Items.Add("\t" + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Contains` check is checking for the number without the `\t`, but then you're adding the item with the `\t`. So the `Contains` check will never succeed.

Try this:

```
int value = rnd.Next(101);
string item = "\t" + value;
if (!lstNumberList.Items.Contains(item))
{
    lstNumberList.Items.Add(item);
}
```